# NSDateFormatter decreases the day of date

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdateformatter

I need to store `Date` variable in `CoreData` in `iOS`

I need to store the Date only without the Time, So I made a formatter that discard the time partition from the `NSDate` variable.
But I have a strange result:
This is my code:

```
    let dateStr = "2016-02-14 11:27:01"

    let df2 = NSDateFormatter()
    df2.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    df2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    print(dateStr)

    if let date = df2.dateFromString(dateStr) {
        df2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        print("-> \(df2.dateFromString(df2.stringFromDate(date)))")
    }
```

and this is the output:

```
2016-02-14 11:27:01
-> Optional(2016-02-13 20:00:00 +0000)
```

Why does the formatter decrease the day by one ?
I tried many dates with same issue

Comment: Is your time zone UTC+4 ?

Comment: yes, but why? @vadian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your time zone is obviously UTC+4.

To get UTC set the time zone accordingly.

```
df2.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
```

But although you see a date 4 hours ago the `NSDate` object is treated correctly depending on your time zone. The `print` command displays always UTC ignoring the time zone information, because `NSDate` is just a wrapper for a `Double` number.